# Is 老鸽 (lit. "old pigeon") slang?

Tags: translation, meaning, slang

I've seen some cases (in stories, on the internet) where people call each other '老鸽'. As the literal meaning 'old pigeon' doesn't make much sense, I think it's slang but I haven't been able to find out the meaning.

So what exactly does '老鸽' mean?

Comment: You mean, homophone of 老哥?

Comment: I've never seen this, can you give an example

Comment: I don't have an exact example ready so I'll use English here, sorry. One I can remember is like this: A: That person has done xyz before, he's such a bad person right? B: But you've done similar things too, 老鸽. => I've seen it a fair share of times, so I think it's more likely a slang than a homophone of 老哥.

Comment: The typos are common on the Internet. Are you talking about 老鸨?

Comment: If it's a typo I think '老哥' is more likely, though a lot of people typing it wrong to '老鸽' is a bit strange, but since I didn't find anything at all regarding it maybe it's actually a homophone-related case of typos. '老鸨' is a bit too far off in meaning.

Comment: @TentacleMonster the stories and internet you mentioned, are they written by the same group of people? For example, is this _a lot of people_ you mentioned all from the same internet forum?

Comment: No, it's random, not from the same group of people. There's the slang 'release the pigeon' that means missing an appointment right, that's why when I see pigeon I assumed it's another slang, but maybe it's just typos.

Answer (score 4):

老鸽 is an intentional typo.  鸽(Pigeon) can mean "get stood up"(被鸽了，被放鸽子) or "stood sb. up"（放某人鸽子）.  So this is the combination of both 'bro' and 'a guy that often does not show up in appointments'.

Comment: this is the correct answer. I've been called this a lot so I know.  The context is something like this via a phone call. A: " Are you here yet?", B: " On my way, 5min", A:" I don't believe you, you 老鸽."

Answer (score 1):

**It will make a lot of sense if you see this word in some video channel comments to mention the holder (Youtuber or uploader on other websites).**

“老” or "老是" by itself means "often".

As is also mentioned in other answers “鸽” is short for the slang "放鸽子" (release a pigeon) which means one can not keep his promise. Nowadays it is a very popular word to describe situations that a channel holder promised to upload some video soon but postponed for a long time. Or an uploader started a weekly series, but skipped some weeks, or just stopped updating that series.

"老哥" means "big brother" or simply "Bro". It has almost exactly the same usage and emotion as "Bro". You can use it to call any male.

To sum up, "老鸽" is a pun. First, it means "老哥" and can be used to call a male fellow, mostly an uploader, but in a joking way. It also means "老鸽", short for “老是放鸽子”, which means "usually cannot keep the promise". It is joking that the uploader is known for often postponing the schedule.

It has other versions like "鸽鸽" which is a pun for "哥哥" and "放鸽子" and "鸽王" which is a pun for "歌王"（king of singers） and "放鸽子之王" (king of procrastination)

**For example:**

A part-time individual game video channel holder posted a message saying "Because of the isolation during the pandemic, the video that was scheduled for the next week is postponed." This is funny for the channel followers because usually, isolation will give him more time at home so that he can have more time to make videos. It is too obvious that he is just trying to find whatever excuse for his procrastination. So a channel follower comment that:

"我来给这位 **老鸽** 翻译一下：咕咕咕咕咕咕咕，咕咕咕，咕咕咕。"

which means：

“let me do some translation for this **habitual postponer**, [mimicking the sound of a pigeon]”

Well, it is not meant to be any offensive. It is just funny.

Answer (score 0):

鸽 is a way saying that missing appointments a lot or not trustworthy. But 老鸽 is actually referring to 老哥, which means like "yo, man" or "hey, bro". This is used online sometimes, not a formal word. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It is not 老鸽.Is 老哥.

Usually, it have two mean. one means brother who are older than the speaker. Another is mean kind of like bro in English.

If you are sure that 老鸽 is the right word ,it can be somebody's nickname.

Comment: I am Taiwanese.My mother tongue is Chinese. Reference myself

Comment: By the way 哥 is used for calling male,not female.